# Select numbers from a message in Java

Tags: java

`" 294618 is your One Time Passcode (OTP) for the request "`

How to extract only the numbers from the String given above?

Comment: Are you guaranteed only one number or multiple numbers?

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: @MuhammedAmjad How is this question related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Following function will return you the first integer that is part of string.

```
public static String getOtp(String string) {

    String sPattern = "[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String s = matcher.group(1);
        return s;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print out all numbers from your String:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" 294618 is your One Time Passcode (OTP) for the request ");
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "294618 is your One Time Passcode (OTP) for the request";

String extractNo= yourString.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
System.out.println(extractNo);
```